# Dealer still plays when user busts... Can't find a way for the user hand to store without it resetting when the dealer goes

Tags: java

Like the title says, i've been messing around making different games in a mini casino. Blackjack however, no matter if the user busts, the dealer will still play. I tried using the hand.getScore and dealerHand.GetScore to allow me to user a while loop for if the user is <= 21 then the dealer will play.

I'm totally baffled right now and it's winding me up, any advice would be great! Thank you very much in advance guys and gals!

I'll attach the classes of code that is being referenced.

App section

```
public class App {
//public static void main(String[] args) {
    public void playNewBlackjack(User player) {
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    Hand hand = new Hand();
    Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
    Game game = new Game();
    Scoring scoring = new Scoring();
    User user = new User();
    Hand dealerHand = new Hand();

    user.setFirstName("What is your first name?");
    user.setSurname("What is your Last name?");
    user.setBalance("How much would you like to deposit?");

    while (user.getBalance() >= 1) {
        user.setBet("How much do you want to bet this time?");
        deck.shuffle();
        int[] ArrayScore = game.main(deck, hand, dealer);
        int CheckWin = scoring.scoringSystem(ArrayScore);

        if (CheckWin == 1) {
            user.updateBalance(user.getBalance() + user.getBet());
            System.out.println("Your total balance is now " + user.getBalance());

        } else if (CheckWin == 2 || CheckWin == 3 || CheckWin == 4) {
            user.updateBalance(user.getBalance() - (user.getBet()));
            System.out.println("Your total balance is now " + user.getBalance());

        }
        deck.resetDeck();
        hand.resetHand();
        dealerHand.resetHand();
    }
```

Main game area

```
public class Game {
public static int[] main(Deck deck, Hand hand, Dealer dealer){
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    hand.add(deck.deal());
    hand.add(deck.deal());
    System.out.println(hand);
    System.out.println(hand.getScore());

    while(hand.getScore() <= 21) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to hit or stick?");
        String hitOrStick = user_input.nextLine();

        if (hitOrStick.equals("hit")){
            hitOption(hand, deck);

        } else if(hitOrStick.equals("stick")){
            System.out.println("Your total hand is " + hand.getScore());
            System.out.println("");
            break;
        }
        if (hand.getScore() == 21){
            System.out.println("Your total hand is " + hand.getScore() + " you must stick");
            break;
        }
        if(hand.getScore() > 21){
            System.out.println("You bust");
            break;
        }
    }

    int dealerScore = dealer.dealerTurn(deck);
    int playerScore = hand.getScore();
    int[] scoreArray = {dealerScore,playerScore};

    return scoreArray;

}

public static void hitOption(Hand hand,Deck deck){
    hand.add(deck.deal());
    System.out.println(hand);
    System.out.println(hand.getScore());

}
```

Dealer

```
public class Dealer {
public static int dealerTurn(Deck deck) {
    Hand hand = new Hand();
    Game game = new Game();
    Hand dealerHand = new Hand();

    dealerHand.add(deck.deal());
    dealerHand.add(deck.deal());
    System.out.println("The dealers cards are:");
    System.out.println(dealerHand);
    System.out.println(dealerHand.getScore());
    System.out.println(hand.getScore()); // to see whether the value is being stored


    while (hand.getScore() <= 21) {  //still assigned as 0
        if (dealerHand.getScore() < 17) {
            System.out.println("The dealer will hit");
            game.hitOption(hand, deck);
        }
        else if (dealerHand.getScore() == 21) {
            System.out.println("The dealer will hits 21");
        }
        else if (dealerHand.getScore() >= 17){
            System.out.println("The dealer will stick");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The dealer will stand");
            System.out.println(dealerHand);
            System.out.println("The dealers score is " + dealerHand.getScore());
            break;
        }
    }
    return hand.getScore();
}
```

Hand

```
public class Hand {
private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

public void add(Card card){
    cards.add(card);
}

public int getScore(){
    int total = 0;
    for(Card card: cards){
        total += card.getScore();
    }
    return total;
}

public String toString() {
    return cards.toString();
}

public void resetHand(){
    cards.clear();
}
```

Score System (Temporary, needs doing properly after the main game fixes)

```
public class Scoring {
public static int scoringSystem(int[] ArrayScore){

     //Dealer = 0
     //User = 1
    if (ArrayScore[0] > 21 && ArrayScore[1] <= 21) {
        System.out.println("The dealer has bust, you win!");
        return 1;

    }
    else if (ArrayScore[1] > 21){
        System.out.println("You have bust, the dealer wins!");
        return 2;

    }
    else if (ArrayScore[0] > ArrayScore[1] && ArrayScore[0] <= 21 || ArrayScore[0] == ArrayScore[1] && ArrayScore[0] <= 21){
        System.out.println("The dealer wins!");
        return 3;
    }
    else {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `dealer.turn()` after your while loop for the users turn. My solution isn't perfect (you need to add a few more lines/functions to make it work exactly how you want) but it at least shows you where your error is.

```
while(hand.getScore() <= 21) {
    System.out.println("Do you want to hit or stick?");
    String hitOrStick = user_input.nextLine();

    if (hitOrStick.equals("hit")){
        hitOption(hand, deck);

    } else if(hitOrStick.equals("stick")){
        System.out.println("Your total hand is " + hand.getScore());
        System.out.println("");
        break;
    }
    if (hand.getScore() == 21){
        System.out.println("Your total hand is " + hand.getScore() + " you must stick");
        break;
    }
    if(hand.getScore() > 21){
        System.out.println("You bust");
        int playerScore = hand.getScore(); // changes
        int[] scoreArray = {0,playerScore}; // changes

        return scoreArray; // returning here prevents dealer.dealerTurn(deck) from being called
    }
}

int dealerScore = dealer.dealerTurn(deck); // this no longer fires off if the user wins/loses
int playerScore = hand.getScore();
int[] scoreArray = {dealerScore,playerScore};

return scoreArray;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked a treat, now I have to fix the issue where it's still hitting even if it's over the players stick and under 21

Comment: If you found that helpful, could you accept it as the answer? and I don't see how you're hitting in that condition. maybe try `"You are at " + hand.getScore() + ". Do you want to hit or stick?"` to help you debug.